# Installation of JQuery snippet not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, code-snippets

I am trying to install the following: http://red-team-design.com/simple-and-effective-dropdown-login-box/

When I hover over it, the color changes. The CSS is shown when I click inspect element.

But when I click on the login tab, it does not open.

What am I doing wrong? How can I find out what I am doing wrong?

I have created a file called custom.js and embedded it.

I am using the Laravel framework.

Comment: Show your form html code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this out of my head, but it seems that the default anchor tag event is not discarded (on `#login-trigger`). You can either pass the event as a variable to the triggered function and call `e.preventDefault();` or call `return false;` at the end of this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#login-trigger').click(function(e){  //add this
    e.preventDefault(); //add this
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');          

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
      else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    })
});
```